# How do I fix Facebook OAuth OAuthException code 191?

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth, google-cloud-functions, facebook-oauth

I'm building an OAuth flow in a Firebase Function.

When a client tries to login through Facebook, I create an UUID for their flow, redirect them to the facebook login dialog in the browser with the above UUID as the value for the state parameter.

I expect the Facebook login dialog to come up, instead I get this error:

> Authentication error: StatusCodeError: 400 - "{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Missing redirect_uri parameter.\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":191,\"fbtrace_id\":\"ASKnZNGGkKhI4UI5mBcX_zl\"}}"

I even tried adding quotes to the redirect_uri in my request

```
...&redirect_uri="<encoded_uri>"
```

which resulted in a different error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

(So I'm guessing I don't need to enclose the parameter in quotes)

---

This is the url I'm redirecting to:

> https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-bitblock-blast.cloudfunctions.net%2Foauth%2Fsignin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback%2F&scope=public_profile&state=1da53893-ee5c-488d-be5c-c7913411c758

This is a version with request_uri not percent encoded just so you can see it clearly (I'M NOT USING THIS)

> https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=https://us-central1-bitblock-blast.cloudfunctions.net/oauth/signin/facebook/callback/&scope=public_profile&state=1da53893-ee5c-488d-be5c-c7913411c758

I've tried opening it directly in the browser, but no luck, same errors.

As you can see, this is my callback endpoint

> https://us-central1-bitblock-blast.cloudfunctions.net/oauth/signin/facebook/callback/

[These are the domains I added in the app's console on Facebook under Settings > Basic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jywIt.png)

[These are the settings and callback URIs I added under Products > Facebook Login > Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOCYx.png)
(As you can see I've tried every possible variation)

[Here you can see my callback being verified as OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Rc3.png)

(Notice that the following variations all work: "...callback/", "...callback", "...callback?state=XXX"

So I don't understand what I'm missing or doing wrong.
I am expecting to be redirected to the Facebook login dialog, and instead I keep getting that 'missing redirect_uri parameter' error.

EDIT: Just to make sure, the Facebook application is also Live.

Comment: That error is not from the login dialog, but from the step that comes after it. You likely have granted all asked for permissions to the app at an earlier point already, so the login dialog doesn’t actually show any more, but redirects right back to your app. The API call that then exchanges the passed `code` value for an access token also needs to be passed the `redirect_uri` parameter, and its value must match the one used in the login dialog call exactly.

Comment: @04FS First of all thanks for the answer, this is helpful!
So you mean my calls to https://www.facebook.com/v5.0/dialog/oauth and https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/oauth/access_token should have the same redirect_uri? This seems a bit weird to me as the callback from the first call is my endpoint which calls the second one to exchange the code for a token.

Comment: Yes, and _while_ making that API call, you need to supply `redirect_uri` again.

Comment: Oh ok I reviewed this and you're right. Still, I'm getting the 'Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings' error. How is this possible? Not the redirect_uri's are EXACTLY the same and as you can see in the screenshots above, the domain is in my settings.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I had left the quotes in the redirect uri from my previous testing. However, now I keep getting the 191 OAuthException missing redirect_uri parameter (anyway you're right, this is when I'm trying to get the access token)